# Whats the difference between Spring and Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know this is not a programmatic questions.

I am a `n00b` to this area coming from `Java EE` background and could not find the difference between the two online (may be I am not a good surfer)

Could someone please share the info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring is a framework alternative to Java EE with three parts:

1. Dependency injection
2. Aspect oriented programming.
3. Libraries for web MVC, persistence, messaging, etc.

Spring MVC is for web MVC.  It's one of the many libraries built into Spring.  You can use other alternatives (e.g. Struts, SEAM, etc.) if you wish and still use Spring.

Answer (score 0):

spring is enterprise framework designed to solve all your problems for enterprise applications. At present they call it as Spring IO, which can be found at spring.io website.

However, Spring MVC is a framework part of the whole stack available to solve the enterprise solutions. This is framework for writing web applications.